# Use tablet as a track pad / drawing pad for computer

Tags: tablet

I was wondering if there is any software out there that would allow me to use my tablet as a track pad / drawing pad on my desktop.

On my desktop, I am currently just using a mouse to edit files in Adobe Creative Suite. One of my designer friends suggested that I get a touch pad / drawing pad to help speed up me work and make it easier to draw things in files. Problem is, those are expensive.

I already have a couple of tablets (iOS and Android) in my house and they have touch screens, so I thought I may be able to use them instead of buying a specifically designed pad.

Is there any software capable of letting me use my tablet as a track pad / drawing pad on my desktop?

- Tablets are iOS and Android
- Computer has both Windows or Linux
- Hopefully I will be able to use the pad in conjunction with the mouse (both can move mouse pointer on screen)

Comment: If you mostly use PhotoShop in the creative suite, you can use adobe's [Eazel](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/adobe-eazel-for-photoshop/id421302663?mt=8). Or look [here - the air display bit](http://sixrevisions.com/tools/how-to-use-ipad-design/).

Comment: Something like these: http://www.remotedroid.net/, http://hipporemote.com/, http://remotemouse.net/? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @shub Thanks for the info. Write it in an answer and I'll mark it correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few methods (I've only ever personally used Eazel (first option), the others are via Google):

1. If you only (or mostly) use Photoshop in the Creative Suite, then use [Adobe's Eazel](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/adobe-eazel-for-photoshop/id421302663?mt=8). I use this for drawing on my iPad and sending to Adobe Photoshop. It is paid, but very useful
2. Or use these:

   - [Remote Droid](http://www.remotedroid.net/):

     > RemoteDroid turns your phone into a wireless keyboard and mouse with touchpad, using your own wireless network
   - [Hippo Remote](http://hipporemote.com/):

     > Turn your iPhone and iPod touch into a wireless keyboard, mouse, remote control and gamepad for your computer.
   - [Remote Mouse](http://remotemouse.net/):

     > Turn your mobile phone or tablet into a set of wireless mouse and keyboard.

Comment: Your link to remote droid does not work.

Comment: Also I can't get remote mouse to connect or scan the QR code